# Logout at Spring Authorization Server doesn’t terminate user session in Keycloak

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, logout, keycloak-services, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to implement an end-user initiated `logout` mechanism.

I have **4** main entities involved.

- **Client:** an `Angular` app registered as a public `OIDC` client on Keycloak
- **Keycloak:** behaves as an identity broker
- **Spring Authorization Server:** identity provider registered on Keycloak
- **Resource Server:** a `Spring Boot` application with a secure `REST` endpoint

When the end-user initiates a `logout`, a call is made by the `Angular` application to Keycloak’s `end_session_endpoint`. I have configured the `logout` URL for my identity provider (`Spring Authorization Server`) in Keycloak as http://localhost:9000/logout which is the default `Spring Security` logout endpoint.

**FYI:** I haven't enabled `BackChannel` or `FrontChannel` logout.

[image]

In the `Network` tab of `Developer Console`, the sequence of calls happen as below:

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/logout?client_id=hello-world&post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&id_token_hint=...
- [http://localhost:9000/logout?state=ff57bb5b-4a79-4e68-bd39-fe7a33ec8788&id_token_hint=...&post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fauth%2Frealms%2FSpringBootKeycloak%2Fbroker%2Foidc%2Fendpoint%2Flogout_response](http://localhost:9000/logout?state=ff57bb5b-4a79-4e68-bd39-fe7a33ec8788&id_token_hint=...)

While inspecting the `DEBUG` logs in the `Spring Authorization Server`, I am able to see the `logout` happen for that particular end-user including invalidating the `JSESSIONID`, however the session doesn’t terminate in Keycloak which causes the user to stay logged in and access the secure `REST` endpoint.

Is the `Spring Authorization Server` expected to return a **specific response back** to Keycloak to convey that the `logout` process is complete at it’s end and that Keycloak can end the session now?

This is my logic for `logout` at `Spring Authorization Server`.

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize -> authorize.mvcMatchers("/hello/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .addFilterAfter(cookieFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:4200");
        
    return http.build();
}
```

I am totally clueless about what I am missing to make Keycloak end the session at it’s end.
Any leads will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update:** A `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter is sent in the `logout` request to the `Spring Authorization Server`. I am **not able to see a redirection happen** to this URI which may be the reason that Keycloak session doesn't terminate.

```
post_logout_redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/broker/oidc/endpoint/logout_response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this to work finally!

The `logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:4200")` is incorrect.

As I mentioned in the **Update** part of my question that Keycloak sends a `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter (inspected the `logout` endpoint in the `Network` calls in Chrome `Developer Console`), the `logoutSuccessUrl` or the `redirectUri` should be set to

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/broker/oidc/endpoint/logout_response

Also, note that the above URL takes in `state` as a request parameter. Initially, it gave me a `400 Bad Request` as I didn't send the `state`.

Since I was required to intercept the `state` parameter when `logout` is initiated at the `Spring Authorization Server`, I added a **custom logout handler** to do the job.

```
@Component
public class IdpLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    private static final String STATE = "state";

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        String state = request.getParameter(STATE);
        try {
            response.sendRedirect(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/broker/oidc/endpoint/logout_response?state="
                            + state);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize -> authorize.mvcMatchers("/hello/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .addFilterAfter(cookieFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class).logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(customLogoutHandler);
```